# encrypt and decrypt a pdf in php with gnupg

Tags: php, gnupg

for a little security reasons I must encrypt (in php) (and decrypt later) some pdf in my server.

How can I do this? I can do it in php with gnupg?

I've try to search in internet some example but I haven't found anything

Can You help me?

Comment: you can passed protect a pdf. (no idea how secure this is). if you encrypt and decrypt on the server that also has he encryption key, your not protecting much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ssh2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) library with the [gnupg](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x110.html) form the command line. I think it is very powerful solution, but You have to be careful with ssh2 library:)

What OS do You prefer?

Comment: Thank You for your reply jakon. I've a server linux

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GnuPG extension](http://www.php.net//manual/en/book.gnupg.php), but for a PDF file, it'd probably be easiest to just fork out to `gpg(1)` with `exec`.

Something like this might work, assuming you have the key in your GPG keychain already:

```
exec(escapeshellcmd("gpg -e -r " . 
                     escapeshellarg($key_id) . " " .
                     escapeshellarg($filename)));
```